# How to programmatically replace sequences of dashes, equals, or asterisks with a solid line (border)?

Tags: replace, ms-word, notepad++, border

### The issue

I am wondering if there is any way to replace every occurrence of a sequence of characters used to simulate a line or border in a text file with a solid or double line?

In MS Word when you type a few dashes and hit enter, autocorrect will convert the dashes to a solid line the length of the page automatically; a few equals + enter gets converted to a double-line.

I have a text file in which I created logical divisions using the following structures:

```
********************

====================

and

--------------------
```

### My questions

1. Is there any way to automatically/programmatically convert any of those sequences (possibly by search and replace?) into a solid-line/border?
2. What workarounds might accomplish this, or is there no solution in this case as far as Microsoft Word is concerned?

Comment: Are you looking for a programming solution, or an end-user solution, specifically? It *sounds* end-user, and the answer that's been posted is end-user, which would make the entire discussion off-topic... It's also not clear if you want this in Word, or in Notepad++?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your question. I've already got line "approximations" in a text file. I want to import that text file (or just simply open it) in `MS WORD` and then run a macro or a simple wildcard regex search and replace to replace all of my line approximations with actual border lines. Another option is to auto convert hundreds of lines that have three or more dashes into a border (the way autocorrect as I type works, but after I've already typed it)

Answer (score 1):

In text files there's no such thing as solid lines, so I propose a workaround to accomplish something very similar to a solid line in a text file using Notepad++.

In Notepad++ you can perform a replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) using the following regex:

```
[=]+|[-]+|[*]+
```

replacing it with a sequence of underscore that is the closer thing to a solid line in a text file.

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]